# How to merge empty partitions to main partition without data loss in main in macOS?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, partition-recovery, merge, macos-mojave

I tried to install Windows in my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) having macOS Mojave. Tried without the bootcamp assistant as directed in the link -
https://fgimian.github.io/blog/2016/03/12/installing-windows-10-on-a-mac-without-bootcamp/

But after re creating the partition as mentioned in the link above, and after the starting of the installation, an error popped up saying - "We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one."
Upon trying to find out a possible solution, I came across -
https://www.reddit.com/r/bootcamp/comments/3t7yai/we_couldnt_create_a_new_partition_or_locate_an/
As I was stuck, the last link having lots of successful results made me understand that I need to have all the partitions combined back to one. Reset the PRAM, and then do the same steps.

To get all the partitions to one, I deleted the ones that showed during the Windows Installation, and formatted them, as the unformatted ones, did not show up in the macOS.

But even after the formatting, the partitions did not show as active in the "Disk Utility", and showed error either upon mounting, restoring or Erasing.

I am tired of trying to install Windows, as there is some or the other error. I have somehow preserved my MacOS thankfully.

I just want to know how can I get back all the partitioned drives into the main drive as free space.

The combined screenshot of the partitions is below :
[image]

And About This Mac shows the storage as below :
[image]

I still have the Windows 10 bootable USB.Do I need to delete(and format) partitions from there first?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. On each of the partitions, click "Erase" at the top. Be sure to select "Mac OS Extended (Journaled).

   [image: Erasing a partition]
2. Next, for each of the partitions, click "Partition" at the top. Then, click the "-" to merge it with your system partition (shown in red below).

   [image: Merging a partition]
3. Done!